# Giving SSH users read-only access to a directory

Tags: ssh, chmod, chown

I'm running Fedora 17 and I want to give several users access to files on my secondary hard drives on /run/media/haukur/. This is what I initially did:

```
chmod -R 755 /run/media/
```

But every time I turn the computer off these permissions are reset to:

```
ls -l /run/media/
drwxr-x---+ 4 root root 80 Jul  5 17:42 haukur
```

The same applies to /run/media/haukur/. I made a symbolic link in every user's home directory pointing to /run/media/haukur/ but they stop working (permission errors) all the time.

What can I do to make these changes permanent?

Edit: I solved the problem by adding the devices to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdc1   /media/a                               ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/sdb1   /media/b                               ext4    defaults        0 0
```

Comment: You could try a `@reboot chmod -R 755 /run/media` in root's crontab.

Comment: Thanks. Will this only be executed once, on the next reboot?

Comment: Fedora has a specific file for executing post boot, check my answer below.

Comment: The `/run` directory is the mount point of an in-memory filesystem (tmpfs). Whatever is in there is recreated at each boot. Given the names, the directories look like mount points. What is the output of the command `cat /proc/mounts`? And plain `mount`? How are these filesystems mounted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Fedora system, the file `/etc/rc.local` contains commands to run after the system has booted and started all services in the runlevel.
If you are looking to fix the permissions when the system boots up, drop `chmod -R 755 /run/media` in the `/etc/rc.local` file.

`/etc/rc.local` is treated like a shell script.

Comment: Thanks, but this did not solve the problem. When Fedora boots, /run/media doesn't exist. It is created when I mount my two other partitions (another annoyance, I'd like this to be done automatically, without authentication). And when it is created it is created with the permissions above.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot add the mountpoints to `/etc/fstab`? Mountpoints listed in fstab are mounted during the boot process.

Comment: No, not really, and that's what I ended up doing. I just didn't know how it was done. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!